# Remedy WSDL escape character for less than not working

Tags: c#, remedy

I built a query in SOAP UI that works fine:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:CHG_ChangeInterface_WS">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:AuthenticationInfo>
         <urn:userName></urn:userName>
         <urn:password></urn:password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:authentication>?</urn:authentication>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:locale>?</urn:locale>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:timeZone>?</urn:timeZone>
      </urn:AuthenticationInfo>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:Change_QueryList_Service>
         <urn:Qualification>('Change Request Status'!="Closed" AND 'Change Request Status'!="Cancelled") AND 'Scheduled Start Date'>"2019-04-22" AND 'Scheduled End Date'&lt;"2019-05-06" </urn:Qualification>

         <urn:startRecord>1</urn:startRecord>
         <urn:maxLimit>10</urn:maxLimit>
      </urn:Change_QueryList_Service>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I make this same call through my C# code this works fine and I get my expected results:

```
 var response = service.Change_QueryList_Service("'Scheduled Start Date' > \"2019-04-22\"", "1", "1000").ToList();
```

When I modify that call to contain some of the range like I did in the SOAP UI example it fails complaining about the XML (which I get):

```
var response = service.Change_QueryList_Service("'Scheduled Start Date' >= \"2019-04-22\" AND 'Scheduled End Date' < \"2019-05-06\"", "1", "1").ToList();
```

I tried escaping the "less than" character with but that also fails (complaining about the qualification line character 66 which is where the escape sequence starts:

```
var response = service.Change_QueryList_Service("'Scheduled Start Date' >= \"2019-04-22\" AND 'Scheduled End Date' &lt; \"2019-05-06\"", "1", "1").ToList();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set 1000 on the third parameter, like on the first example. 
Also in the Remedy documentation the names of the fields appears with underscore instead of spaces:

```
Sheduled_Start_Date
```

[BMC Remedy 8 - Change_Querylist](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/change80/change_query_service-and-change_querylist_service-functions-151453968.html)